# C++ Correct way to use headers

Tags: c++

I'm by no means new to using headers in programs, but I've recently run into a strange problem.

```
#ifndef PLAYER_HEADER_GUARDS
#define PLAYER_HEADER_GUARDS

#include "CollidableObject.h"
#include "Includes.h"

extern const int ANIMATION_EXTENDER;
extern class MapSystem *mapSystem;

class Player : public CollidableObject
{
     //declaration of rest of the class
};

#endif
```

I have a lot of classes split across several files (and their respective headers), but here is my current problem : even though I have already included CollidableObject.h, the compiler (CodeBlocks) throws an error

```
Player.h|12|error: expected class-name before '{' token|
```

The problem arises from the " : public CollidableObject" part of the code, since the program worked fine before I added that. Shouldn't including the CollidableObject header (I'm not posting it, but it basically looks just the same, and defines the class CollidableObject) remove this kind of a problem? Further,

```
extern class MapSystem *mapSystem;
```

This statement should, to the best of my knowledge, compile fine without the extra "class" after extern, but if I remove the class keyword, it throws an error "expected type qualifier before * token". The class MapSystem has also been defined previously, and it should work fine - but without the class keyword, it doesn't.

So that brings me to my question - what mistake am I making in my header files, that is leading to such problems? No multi-filed project that I worked on before had such problems.

Comment: Is Player.h included in CollidableObject.h?

Comment: No, it's not, since CollidableObject class doesn't require player.h

Comment: And is it included in any file included in CollidableObject? That is, something like this: CollidableObject includes A.h, which includes B.h, ... which includes N.h, which includes Player.h.

Comment: Apparently it does, and that was what caused the problem.

Thanks a bunch for pointing that out! :)

Comment: Then refer to Mike Seymour's answer. I recommend that you look up concepts like circular dependency and forward declaration in relation to C++. If you become familiar with the common issues around those your design skills will improve vastly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like either `"CollidableObject.h"` or `"Includes.h"` tries to reinclude `"Player.h"`, resulting in a circular dependency. The result is that `Player` ends up being defined before `CollidableObject`, so the latter name is not declared at that point.

Make sure neither of these headers, nor any of their dependencies, include `"Player.h"`. You might need to add forward declarations of `class Player;` if anything needs to use that name.

Also check that `"CollidableObject.h"` does actually define `class CollidableObject` (perhaps there's a spelling mistake?), and has a uniquely named include guard.

As for the second question:

```
extern class MapSystem *mapSystem;
```

This doubles up as a declaration of `class MapSystem`, so doesn't require a previous declaration.

```
extern MapSystem *mapSystem;
```

This does not declare `MapSystem` (it only indicates that it's a type name, not a class), so it does require a previous declaration.

Comment: Regarding the second problem, shouldn't including the header (that contains the definition) forward declare the class? I mean, at the beginning of file, if MaySystem.h has not been included, it will include it, and hence have a declaration. If it has already been included, the header guards will prevent it from declaring it again, but since it has already been already been declared, there should be no need to declare it again. One way or the other, why do I need to declare it again?

Comment: @user3541787: Yes, a definition is also a declaration, so if you were to include the header that defined `MapSystem`, you wouldn't need another declaration. But as far as I can see, you're not including it (and probably shouldn't), so you do need a declaration.